# append list in another by prolog using only 2 lists

Tags: list, prolog, append

if I have a list1 = [1,2,3] and list2 = [4,5,6] how I make the output[1,2,3,4,5,6] without using another empty list ?

by using 3rd empty list the code 'll be :

```
domains
l = integer*

predicates
append(l,l,l)

clauses
append([],X,X)
append( [H|T], X, [H|T2]):- append(T,X,T2).
```

I tried to adapt the code but the prog crash. I think because of endless loop(recursion)

```
predicate
append(l,l)
clauses
append(X,[]):- append(X,X).
append( X, [_|T] ):- append(X,T).
```

Comment: In your adapted code, you need 3 arguments, not 2. In Prolog, you can modify a variable once it's instantiated. So you can't append to `[1,2,3]` by calling, `append([1,2,3], [4,5,6])`.

Comment: This is not Prolog, this is some Prolog derivative (Turbo-Prolog? Visual Prolog?) but the only way to do what you claim you need would be to actually output the lists one after the other.

Comment: but I wan to make it by only 2 arguments !.. you mean I "can't" ?!

Comment: yup this is turbo. I didn't know there is a difference !!

Comment: You want to, you have to, or you think you should? In normal Prolog, "returning" a value or "overwriting" an argument both don't make much sense.

Comment: I want to .. the idea just came to my head and I wanted to implement it. and here I learned new thing.. I can't modify the instantiated variable ... thanks guys